# Unable to remove item from customer shopping cart from admin panel

Tags: admin, cart, shopping-cart, magento2.3.5

I am using magento 2.3.5p2 Community Edition ( open source one )

I encountered this issue in which when trying to remove an item from a customer cart via admin panel, an error as below appear

[image]

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in /project/project01/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Quote/item/CartitemProcessor.php:86 Stack trace: #0 /project/project01/generated/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Model/Quote/item/CartitemProcessor/Proxy.php(103): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Quote\item\CartitemProcessor >processOptions(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\item)) #1 /project/project01/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/item/CartitemOptions Processor.php(84): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Quote item\CartitemProcessor Proxy-processOptions(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\item)) #2 /project/project01/vendor/magento/module quote/Model/Quote/item/CartitemPersister.php(115): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\item\CartitemOptionsProcessor->addProductOptions('configurable, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\item)) #3 /project/project01/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository/SaveHandler.php(97): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\item\CartitemPersister->save(Object(Magent in /project/project01/vendor/magento/module-configurable product/Model/Quote/item/CartitemProcessor.php on line 86`

[image]

I want to remove the item from the customer cart because the item is currently disabled and the customer cannot proceed to checkout unless the item is removed

Kindly help

Comment: Problem fixed, need to delete the item through database, need run 

```SELECT qi.item_id ,q.*, qi.* FROM quote q LEFT JOIN quote_item qi
ON q.entity_id = qi.quote_id
WHERE q.customer_id = "111111"
AND qi.product_id IN ("11111","11112")
AND is_active = 1;``` then delete the item from quote_item table based on its item_id